# Two 14S Lithium-Ion batteries have different charging speeds: the smallest is slower than the higher capacity one

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charging, time, capacity

Long story short: I built one 14S battery last year, using [Molicell P42A](https://www.molicel.com/wp-content/uploads/INR21700P42A-V4-80092.pdf) cells. 6 cells in parallel for every series. So, around 58.8V total voltage on the battery.
Recently I made another battery having 7 [Molicell P45B](https://www.molicel.com/inr21700-p45b/) cells in parallel to increase the capacity but keeping it at 14S to have the same output voltage.
The first battery takes around 3 to 4 hours to charge. The second, only 1.5h, more or less.
How's that possible? The second battery should take more time to charge, but it takes way less, instead.
The charger I used is the same, it's a SKYRC PC2500. For the values I quickly read during charge, it looks like the second battery goes on fast charge mode, but I never select that mode, I only use the standard charging mode. I'll charge both of them in the next days to provide more accurate data.

Is there something on their datasheets that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you measured the current into each? Start from same SoC? Terminate charge using same criteria?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the internal resistance: the older battery has a significantly higher internal resistance.

At the same current during the CC stage of CCCV charging, the older battery reaches the CV threshold sooner (at a lower SoC) because there is a higher voltage increase in the high-resistance battery. Then the CV stage completes charging the older battery. That stage takes longer because it started at a lower SoC level.

[image]